# How to access data from the SVG map with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, svg, vuejs2

I use SVG map of Austria. Each province has "title" attribute which contains a name of the province.

[full example available in the snippet below]

Outside the map in my HTML I have a paragraph, where I want to display the name of the province that was clicked by the user.

{{ province }}

How can I achieve that?

Here is my snippet with my code:
https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/marektchas/500840?view=project

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the `svg` part you can add a click event on each `path`:

```
<path @click="setProvince('Burgenland')" id="AT-1" title="Burgenland" class="land" d="..." />
```

And add a method in your script:

```
methods: {
  setProvince (title) {
    this.province = title
  }
}
```

---

**Updated answer**

If you have a lot of provinces, you can add the click event on `mounted` by selecting all the `<path>` selectors (or class name or any selector you find relevant for your case):

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    province: null
  },
  mounted () {
    this.addClickHandler()
  },
  methods: {
    setProvince (title) {
      this.province = title
    },
    addClickHandler () {
      let paths = this.$el.querySelectorAll('path')
      paths.forEach(el => {
        let title = el.attributes.title.value
        el.addEventListener('click', () => {
          this.setProvince(title)
        })
      })
    }
  }
});
```

There's no need of `@click` in template anymore this way.
[Live example here](https://jsfiddle.net/StpFlp_DDK/gLybwpjv/)

Comment: Adding a separated @click event to each of the province (especially if the map contains hundreds of them) doesn't seem like a good practice. However, I have tried your solution with exactly the same code and it doesn't work

Comment: @MarekHas If you have a lot of provinces, you can add an event listener on mounted. I updated my answer with a working live example.

Comment: One more question. How your code should look like if I want to display other data from the SVG element? For example, if I also want to display the value of ID attribute within {{ id }} element? So if I click on the province it will display the name of the province and it's ID in the separated <p> {{ id }} </p

Comment: you can add in data `id: null` and in the `forEach` loop, retrieve the id like: `let id = el.id`. Then you can do `el.addEventListener('click', () => { this.province = title this.id = id })`.There's no need for the `setProvince` method this way. Updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/StpFlp_DDK/gLybwpjv/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about event delegation. You should be able to attach an event handler to the svg root and get events for any element inside the svg

https://recursive.codes/blog/post/34

https://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events